# jQuery Each Loop to push data into JSON Object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, push, each

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here. I have several elements on screen with class `.cp_select`. I need to loop through them and grab the attributes of "x" and "y". This by itself works fine. Then I need to assemble a `JSON` obj with a sub array child `positions` and push each looping x/y set into it. I'm then going to use the array in PHP with `json_decode()`, loop through that child `positions` and process it on the PHP side. I just can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

```
$(".pix_select_btn").click(function() {
    
    var poz = {}
    var poz_xy = {}
    $(".cp_select").each(function() {
        
        var pix = $(this)
        poz_xy = {"x" : pix.attr("x"), "y" : pix.attr("y")};
        poz['positions'].push(pos_xy)
                    
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(poz))
    console.log();
})
```

Comment: You have to create the `poz.positions` property before you can push onto it.

Comment: `var poz = {positions: []}`

Comment: Aren't you getting an error saying that `undefined` has no property `push`?

Comment: Hi Barmar - yes I am. I should have mentioned that. Just didn't know how to correct it

Comment: Ahhh got it. Thank you. I also had a typo. Still cleaning it up

Comment: BTW, there's no need to declare `poz_xy` outside the `.each()` function.

Comment: @barmar thank you were a big help here. Been at it for days. Do you want to 'officially' answer the question. B/c that worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the array before you can push into it.

```js
$(".pix_select_btn").click(function() {

  var poz = {positions: []}
  $(".cp_select").each(function() {

    var pix = $(this)
    var poz_xy = {
      "x": pix.attr("x"),
      "y": pix.attr("y")
    };
    poz.positions.push(pos_xy)

  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(poz));
})
```

You can also simplify it by using `map()`.

```js
$(".pix_select_btn").click(function() {

  var poz = {
    positions: $(".cp_select").map(function() {
      var pix = $(this)
      return {
        "x": pix.attr("x"),
        "y": pix.attr("y")
      };
    }).get(); // .get() converts from jQuery object to array
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(poz));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that PHP runs in server and JS run in client, so you don't be able to use var poz in PHP.

You need to send a XHR request to catch the values in the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ty

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).